# New heavens and new lands in the Zohar

Tags: torah-study, zohar, heaven

The Zohar [Introduction 4a] states that new interpretations of the Torah rise, are blessed and crowned by God, and create a "new heaven".

It then adds that "all the other new interpretations of the Torah present themselves before the Holy One, blessed be He, ascend and become 'lands of life', then descend and become absorbed into one land, whereby a new land emerges through that new discovery in the Torah. This is implied in the verse: 'For as the new heavens and the new earth, which I am making, rise up before me…' [Isaiah 64:22]."

I don't understand the difference between the first and second categories.  The wording implies to me that the second category is less important than the first.  Is that the case?  If so, why?  Is the "fate" of each new interpretation random?

Comment: What's there to downvote in "I don't understand this passage"?  If the meaning is obvious, just give it.  Isn't that what we are here for?